# Can jsf.js be renamed

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

We are migrating from an old version of a customer facing application to a new version (both using JSF 2.1.7). 
Our application supports multiple client websites say, client A and client B.

We want to phase roll out the new application one client at a time. We are managing this in our IIS proxy layer by redirecting all client A requests to server 1 (that is the old application) and client B to server2 (the new application).

However, the issue is that the `jsf.js` is always picked up from server 1, even for requests from client B (server2). This is possibly causing view state issues and client B does not work (if getting the `jsf.js` from a different server). Client A works fine.

Is there any way that I can rename the `jsf.js`? I looked in the `/META-INF` folder of `jsf-impl.jar`, however I could not find anything which I can change.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the concrete problem. Is the concrete problem that the client is still using a cached version of jsf.js instead of the updated version? And this problem is solved when the client does a hard refresh in browser by itself by pressing Ctrl+F5 or so, but you'd rather not tell all clients to do so? In other words, theoretically just appending a "version" request parameter to the generated URL of `jsf.js` should also suffice to fix your problem?

Comment: No is not a caching issue. My question is how can I rename the javax.faces.resources/jsf.js.xhtml to say javax.faces.resource.new/jsf.js.xhtml

Comment: Okay, just wanted to avoid that you after all went in the wrong direction of fixing the problem :)

Comment: Essentially I am asking if there is a way I can over ride the ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER=/javax.faces.resource